# HTML 5 specific element support in older browsers via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, backwards-compatibility, browser-support

Is there a javascript solution to make the canvas tag or the video tag in HTML5 behave more like HTML5 in older/current browsers that don't support it?

The canvas tag should ideally behave like the it would in HTML5 supportive browsers, but the video tag is also good if it's replaced with alternate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the canvas in Internet Explorer using [this library](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/).  There is also [this library](http://code.google.com/p/html5-now/) for doing the same with HTML 5 in general and [this one](http://code.google.com/p/canvas-text/) for drawing text on a canvas.  [Here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-canvas/) is a canvas library for GWT (which of course gets compiled to javascript).

**Edit:** [Here is a library](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) to add svg support to older browsers.